# Django: base.html "TemplateDoesNotExist at / error" and project structure

Tags: python, django

When in my home.html (or any other .html) I try to extend my base.html file with this

```
{% extends "static/src/base.html" %}
```

I get this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at / error
```

Also, I'm about to start my first "serious" project and so I'm trying to do things a little less amateurish starting with my project structure. This is what I've come so far following the clues I got from other site, but I'd like to have some opinion from people with more experience than me if this is a good way to start the project. In particular, I'm a little confused about where to put the base.html file. Is it ok to put it in the src folder or should I put it with the navbar.html/footer.html/etc page or navbar.html/footer.html/etc should go in the src folder instead?

This is my project structure:

```
website_name
- core (where is the settings.py and where I put homepage, news page, contact and about us page...) 

- app name_1 (like members)

- app name_2 

- media
--  img
--  upload (user ulploaded excel file)
---   excel_file.csv 
--   download (for user to download file)

- static
--  src
---  base.html
---  style.css
--  dist
---  style.css
--  node_modules
--  [...]

- template
--  core
---   home.html
---   news_list.html
---   news_delete.html
---   [...]
--  app name_1
--  app name_2
--  navbar.html
--  footbar.html
--  [...]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

normal structure is to put templates in app folder:

```
- core
-- templates
--- core
---- my_base_template.html

- app_name1
-- templates
--- app_name1
---- my_base_template.html

- app_name2
-- templates
--- app_name2
---- my_template1.html
        {% extends "app_name1/my_base_template.html" %}
         ....

---- my_template2.html
        {% extends "core/my_base_template.html" %}
```

With settings correctly setup the template engine will look for template files in the app/templates/ folders automatically.

So please check the settings.py for TEMPLATES -> APP_DIRS=True from Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/ :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

logically templates are not static but are rendered at run time, so they do not make sense inside the static folder structure.